# How to generate bodies with different widths but have the same distance between them?

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural

I try to make a procedurally generated bookshelf, using geometry nodes and I made the books have different heights, lengths, and widths given by random nodes, but now I want to make those books have the same distance between them, basically, I want a book to start right from the edge of the previous one. I tried using a bounding box node but I did not succeed.
[image]

This is how the books are being generated right now, I need them to have no gap between them no matter the width of the book.
[image]

This is what I tried so far.